# Foreign key the extended ID

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have 3 tables that extend a class along with it's properties
Is it possible to make the extended id a foreign key and the principal id a primary key,i tried with

```java
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "id_user"))
```

but no result,in my case i have a journalist that extend a user ,i want the id_user a foreign key and the id_journalist a primary key.
For now i am able only to get id_user a primary key and journalist_id: unique